# Integral exponential and trig

Tags: calculus

Integral of $e^x$cos(x)sin(x)dx

I used the trig identity to get

$1/2$ integral of $e^x$sin(2x)

This is where im stuck.

on wolfram it shows an identity that is used for this problem but Ive never seen this identity before. Is this the correct way to solve this integral? and are there other identities like this?

[image: Identity]

Comment: Two integrations by parts will do it.

Comment: Why don't you differentiate the right side and check whether it equals the left hand??

Comment: To obtain that identity apply integration by parts twice. Then you'll get that integral again on the right-hand side, but with a coefficient not equal to $1$. Hence you'll be able to find its value.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is derived by application of Integration by Parts. I will do the general derivation here, with the hopes that the specific case should then be obvious.
$$\int e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)-\int\frac{\beta}{\alpha}e^{\alpha x} \cos(\beta x)dx$$
Now, applying this again to the right hand integral,
$$\int\frac{\beta}{\alpha}e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)dx=\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)+\int\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)$$
If we denote our original integral by $I$, then we can bring these results together to see that$$I=\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}}e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)-\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}I$$
From which your given formula can be shown - I will leave the algebra as an exercise for you.

Comment: I followed your steps and I got everything until the last step. The last part of the equation is where im having trouble. I got I = $e^x$sin(2x) - 2$e^x$cos(2x) + 4I. I dont see how to get -4I because i get - -4I when doing integration by parts.

Comment: You must have made a mistake in your working - please check it